# PVC conduit, service line with siding offset

Tags: electrical

I am updating our service line and moving it to another part of our home, as per request of the energy supplier.  I have installed the new panel and meter socket. However I am unsure how to run the pvc conduit up the side of our home.

The house has an offset line in the siding of three inches in between the first and second story.  Should I cu a groove in the siding on the second story, or use offset fittings?  Or is there another solution?[image: View of new service location]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Where in the world are you located?

Answer (score 4):

My first choice: Use standoffs to keep the line clear of the house by enough distance to clear the bump, with straight conduit.

Second choice: Given it's PVC either rent a blanket heater or get creative with boiling water and bend yourself a section (rather like an inchworm) that fits around the bump. Make it rather gentle/sweeping so that it's not too much trouble to get wires through it. You could cobble something with 15 or 22 degree bends and couplings, but PVC is easy enough to bend with heat, and a straight stick that you bend is a lot cheaper than a bunch of pre-bent sweeps and couplings - it's also smoother inside.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend EMT. It will look nicer longer.  I wouldn't cut the house; bad on many fronts.  I would use EMT 22.5* factory bends. Three should work.  You may need to lay it over a bit. This will keep the pipe close to the building; the best look.